# Hibernate: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, transactions

I'm new to Hibernate. Using version 3 and having the following issue.

I'm using hibernatetool ant task to generate DAO classes

When I ran my first unit test, I got the following error:

> No CurrentSessionContext configured! org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   No CurrentSessionContext configured!at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:542)

So I did a google search and added this line to my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

After that, I got the following error when trying to persist an object:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction

Very well, so i manually began and commited a transaction.

So i  around my persist as such:
Code:

```
 Transaction tx=null;
 tx = session.beginTransaction();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
```

Success!

So, my questions are:

1. All operations must explicitly be part of a transaction, then why did the Hibernate tools code generator not put that in my DAO as well? is it possible to add these lines too through ant task,then how?

> tx = session.beginTransaction();

2. What is a CurrentSessionContext? I supplied the value "thread". what does that mean? What are the other options?

Comment: Where you get a session for it `tx = session.beginTransaction();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Spring-Annotations -

> "@Transactional"

to minimize your own effort...

..that is the first adequate example, what I just found :

http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-with-hibernate-persistence-and-transactions-example

which is looks like:

```
...  
@Override
  @Transactional
  public void insertUser(User user) {
    userDAO.insertUser(user);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public User getUserById(int userId) {
    return userDAO.getUserById(userId);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public User getUser(String username) {
    return userDAO.getUser(username);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userDAO.getUsers();
  }
```